# Serverless .yml error when running serverless deploy

Tags: javascript, serverless, serverless-framework, aws-serverless

I get the error: "Cannot resolve serverless.yml: Variables resolution errored with:

- Cannot resolve variable at "resources.Resources.ClientsTable.Properties.TableName": Value not found at "self" source" when I try to run the yarn deploy command on my serverless project.

I was hoping somebody could point me in the proper direction as I am unsure why the TableName property can not be resolved.

Thanks,

Tate

```
# Welcome to Serverless!
#
# This file is the main config file for your service.
# It's very minimal at this point and uses default values.
# You can always add more config options for more control.
# We've included some commented out config examples here.
# Just uncomment any of them to get that config option.
#
# For full config options, check the docs:
#    docs.serverless.com
#
# Happy Coding!

service: auto-garden-server
# app and org for use with dashboard.serverless.com
#app: your-app-name
#org: your-org-name

# You can pin your service to only deploy with a specific Serverless version
# Check out our docs for more details
frameworkVersion: "3"

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  lambdaHashingVersion: 20201221
  stage: ${opt:stage, 'dev'}

region: ca-central-1

iam:
  role:
    statements:
      - Effect: Allow
        Action:
          - "dynamodb:PutItem"
          - "dynamodb:DeleteItem"
          - "dynamodb:Scan"
        Resource: 
          - { "Fn::GetAtt": ["ClientsTable", "Arn"] }

environment:
  CLIENTS_TABLE_NAME: ${self:provider.stage}WSClients
  WSSAPIGATEWAYENPOINT:
    Fn::Join:
      - ""
      - - "https://"
        - Ref: WebsocketsApi
        - ".execute-api"
        - Ref: AWS::Region
        - ".amazonaws.com/${sls:stage}"

functions:
  websocketHandler:
    handler: src/handlers.handle
    events:
      - websocket:
          route: $connect
      - websocket:
          route: $disconnect
      - websocket:
          route: $msg

plugins:
  - serverless-plugin-typescript

resources:
  Resources:
    ClientsTable:
      Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
      Properties:
        TableName: ${self:provider.environment.CLIENTS_TABLE_NAME}
        ProvisionedThroughput:
          ReadCapacityUnits: 1
          WriteCapacityUnits: 1
        AttributeDefinitions:
          - AttributeName: connectionId
            AttributeType: S
        KeySchema:
          - AttributeName: connectionId
            KeyType: HASH
```

I am following a tutorial and am unsure about what to do with this error. I double checked syntax.

Answer (score 1):

you environment section seems to be in the wrong place.
it should look something like below:

```
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  lambdaHashingVersion: 20201221
  stage: ${opt:stage, 'dev'}
  environment:
    CLIENTS_TABLE_NAME: ${self:provider.stage}WSClients
    WSSAPIGATEWAYENPOINT:
      Fn::Join:
        - ""
        - - "https://"
          - Ref: WebsocketsApi
          - ".execute-api"
          - Ref: AWS::Region
          - ".amazonaws.com/${sls:stage}"
```

This would fix your error and also include this environment variable in your all your lambda functions automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Five areas I would like to touch.

#Flip your region to: `us-east-1`

#Setting `20201221` for `provider.lambdaHashingVersion` is no longer effective as a new hashing algorithm is now used by default. Remove this setting completely, see below an example.

#The `region` and `iam` field are under the provider

#Move your environment towards the provider as below

#Finally, update the runtime to  accepted `runtime: nodejs12.x` `nodejs14.x`

```
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs14.x
  stage: ${opt:stage, 'dev'}
  environment:
    CLIENTS_TABLE_NAME: ${self:provider.stage}WSClients
    WSSAPIGATEWAYENDPOINT:
      Fn::Join:
        - ""
        - - "https://"
          - Ref: WebsocketsApi
          - ".execute-api."
          - Ref: AWS::Region
          - ".amazonaws.com/${sls:stage}"

# you can overwrite defaults here
#  stage: dev
  region: us-east-1

# you can add statements to the Lambda function's IAM Role here
  iam:
    role:
      statements:
        - Effect: "Allow"
          Action:
            - "dynamodb:PutItem"
            - "dynamodb:DeleteItem"
            - "dynamodb:Scan"
          Resource: 
            - { "Fn::GetAtt": ["ClientsTable", "Arn" ]  }
```